# Stop search Active Directory when not available

Tags: active-directory

I have a PC laptop with Windows 8.1 at work and we use AD (Active Directory). But at home there is no AD.  How can I prevent Windows spend time search AD on Network at home even if it always fail?

Comment: I'm not understanding what you mean by "search AD". Can you clarify your question and add some details?

Comment: Ok, at home when I start laptop and Windows there is a delay until I can start to work. Reason is that it search for a  nonexisting AD Network. After a while it give up and continue. I want to prevent that search. For exempel by hold Shift key or something.

Comment: Question might be better on superuser. Usual work around for this (last I heard) was to disconnect any network connections when starting/logging in. That was easier with hardware wireless switches.